# VSIX - Add item to "File" > "New" menu

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

Is it possible somehow to add a menu item to the "File" > "New" menu of Visual Studio from within a VSIX extension?

There is probably a special GUID that we could use in the .vsct file, but where can we find that please?

Comment: Hi, please try to use this parameter IDG_VS_FILE_FILE or you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/guids-and-ids-of-visual-studio-menus?view=vs-2019#groups-on-visual-studio-menus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Command Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.CommandExplorer) extension to find out where to place your command.